# Show DataGrid inside DataGrid when row is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF forme `Etudiant` i need to show other datagrid when a row in `Etudiant` is clicked named `Epreuve` and the same work to display other datagrid named `Module` when a row is selected in `Epreuve` and i need the event to fill it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fill the inside datagrid you can use **LoadingRowDetails** Event

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Condidat" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRowDetails="Condidat_LoadRowDetails"  CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="345" Width="652">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="Epreuve" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRowDetails="Epreuve_LoadRowDetails" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid x:Name="Module" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```